# Update gitlab badges

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci

## Setup

On a self-hosted Gitlab instance, we have a python package. A CI is set up to be triggered for every merge request into the `main` branch to run unit tests, and if that succeeds, then to build and release the new version into registry.

It's set in settings so that only fast forward merge requests can be merged.

## Issue

Recently, we have set up a badge to display pipeline status. This has been done following the [documentation](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/badges.html#example-project-badge-pipeline-status). If we now run a pipeline on the `main` branch manually, it's working fine.

However, whenever a merge request is approved and merged, the status gets changed to `unknown`. It shows appropriate labels only when it's run manually on the `main` branch, not on a feature or bugfix branch as part of CI.

## Question

Since the latest commit id remains same for both the merge request source branch and the updated `main` branch, my expectation was that it should show status of the same. Why is that not happening. (I have verified that using squashing does not have any effect, as even a single test commit leads to `unknown`.)

---

## Configurations

Workflow Rule (run for all non-push events)

```yaml
workflow:
    rules:
        - if: '$CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE == "push"'
          when: never
        - when: always
```

Badge Settings

```
Name: Pipeline Status
Link: https://<our_gitlab_url>/%{project_path}/-/commits/%{default_branch}
Badge Image URL: https://<our_gitlab_url>/%{project_path}/badges/%{default_branch}/pipeline.svg
```

Comment: Asked on Gitlab forum yesterday, which attracted no response so far: https://forum.gitlab.com/t/pipeline-status-badge-auto-update/68106

Comment: Sounds like a case of [gitlab#215530 (pipeline badges only reflect "commit" pipelines.  should have separate pipeline badges for different pipeline triggers)](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/issues/215530). Please upvote that issue, if you agree.

Comment: Is a branch pipeline created on the main branch when an MR is merged to the branch? Can you provide your CI configuration and the badge settings you are using?

Comment: @sytech : Added workflow rules and badge settings. To anser your question, no we don't have a rule to trigger a run when MR is merged, because it's not intuitive. Since we allow only fast forward merges, there should not be any difference whatsoever.